# Is it possible to use closure and recursive approach for nested arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array, closures

I need to count vowels in nested array, and I'd like to do it with closure to avoid global namespace pollution.
Here's my code:

```
let nestedArr = [
    "Elie",
    ["Matt", ["Tim"]],
    ["Colt", ["Whiskey", ["Janey"], "Tom"]],
    "Lorien"
];


function countVowels() {
    let vowelsCount = 0;
    let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    return function foo(arr) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (typeof arr[i] === 'string') {
                for (let letter of arr[i]) {
                    if (vowels.includes(letter.toLowerCase())) {
                        vowelsCount++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return foo(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return vowelsCount;
    }
}

const counter = countVowels();
console.log(counter(nestedArr));
```

I expect correct number of vowels, but get 5. I tried to debug and see it just stops after "Tim" which is the deepest subarray, so obviously my function does not go level up and I am missing something.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function works just fine if you just change

```
return foo(arr[i]);
```

To:

```
foo(arr[i]);
```

You need to let the entire loop run (obviously), the return makes it stop earlier.

```js
let nestedArr = [
    "Elie",
    ["Matt", ["Tim"]],
    ["Colt", ["Whiskey", ["Janey"], "Tom"]],
    "Lorien"
];


function countVowels() {
    let vowelsCount = 0;
    let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    return function foo(arr) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (typeof arr[i] === 'string') {
                for (let letter of arr[i]) {
                    if (vowels.includes(letter.toLowerCase())) {
                        vowelsCount++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
               foo(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return vowelsCount;
    }
}

const counter = countVowels();
console.log(counter(nestedArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the nested function, you can declare a single recursive function and still keep everything self-contained.

```js
const countVowels = (arr) => {
  const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
  const vowel_count = (s) => [...s].filter((c) => vowels.includes(c.toLowerCase())).length;

  let vowels_total = 0;

  for (const e of arr) {
    vowels_total += Array.isArray(e) ? countVowels(e) : vowel_count(e);
  }

  return vowels_total;
};

const nestedArr = ['Elie', ['Matt', ['Tim']], ['Colt', ['Whiskey', ['Janey'], 'Tom']], 'Lorien'];

console.log(countVowels(nestedArr));
```

Or, foregoing recursion with a curried closure using [`Array#flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) (to `Infinity`)

```js
const countVowels = (
  (v) => (arr) =>
    [...arr.flat(Infinity).join('')].filter((c) => v.includes(c.toLowerCase())).length
)(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']);

const nestedArr = ['Elie', ['Matt', ['Tim']], ['Colt', ['Whiskey', ['Janey'], 'Tom']], 'Lorien'];

console.log(countVowels(nestedArr));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let nestedArr = [
  'Elie',
  ['Matt', ['Tim']],
  ['Colt', ['Whiskey', ['Janey'], 'Tom']],
  'Lorien',
];

function countVowels(str) {
  return str.match(/['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']/gi)?.length || 0;
}

function vowelsAmount(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((accumulator, currentElement) => {
    return Array.isArray(currentElement)
      ? (accumulator += vowelsAmount(currentElement))
      : (accumulator += countVowels(currentElement));
  }, 0);
}

console.log(vowelsAmount(nestedArr));
```

Comment: that regexp is [not doing what you think it's doing](https://regex101.com/r/W6Mq4c/1). it is matching literal `'` and `,` and ` ` characters

Answer (score 0):

This mostly sounds like an exercise to learn recursion.  If so, I leave you to the other fine recursive answers here.

But a simple alternative is to note the `toString` format for Arrays, and realize that we can simply apply our tests to the result of that, leaving some very simple code:

```js
const countVowels = (a) =>
  [... a .toString () .toLowerCase ()] .filter (c => 'aeiou' .includes (c)) .length

const nestedArr = ['Elie', ['Matt', ['Tim']], ['Colt', ['Whiskey', ['Janey'], 'Tom']], 'Lorien']

console .log (countVowels (nestedArr))
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignments, and other side effects. Here's one way we can rewrite the program using a type analysis and [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)

**string**

1. If the input `t` is less than one character, there is nothing to count. Return the empty sum, 0.
2. (inductive) `t` has at least 1 character. Transform the first character to a 1 if it is a vowel, otherwise a 0, and add it to the result of the sub-problem.

**array**

1. If the input `t` has less than one element, there is nothing to count. Return the empty sum, 0
2. (inductive) `t` has at least one element. Count the vowels of the first element and add it to the result of the sub-problem.

**any other type**

- If the input `t` is not a string nor an array, throw an error to notify the caller that we cannot count vowels for that input type.

```js
function countVowels (t) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case String:
      if (t.length < 1)
        return 0                                             // 1
      else
        return isVowel(t[0]) + countVowels(t.slice(1))       // 2
    case Array:
      if (t.length < 1)
        return 0                                             // 1
      else
        return countVowels(t[0]) + countVowels(t.slice(1))   // 2
    default:
      throw Error(`cannot count input type: {t?.constructor}`)
  }
}

function isVowel (t) {
  switch (t.toLowerCase()) {
    case "a":
    case "e":
    case "i":
    case "o":
    case "u":
      return true
    default:
      return false
  }
}

const nestedArr =
  ['Elie', ['Matt', ['Tim']], ['Colt', ['Whiskey', ['Janey'], 'Tom']], 'Lorien']

console.log(countVowels(nestedArr))
```

```js
14
```